# how to make query to don't bring field if exists in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to make a query that bring all the document however if some specific field exists remove field from document and bring all the rest fields from document. 
For example if I have 3 documents in mongodb I want to get all the document `where aptype = "periodic"` and if the `cancel_date` field exists in document just get document without `cancel_date` field

```
{  
   "_id":"8de3e5ec-caa9-4497-89a9-239713e2a2ed",
   "user_id":"6b54be23-0880-4e22-8882-93feea935f12",
   "weekend_price":60000,
   "weekend_wage":40000,
   "active":1,
   "dows":[  
      "2",
      "1",
      "6"
   ],
   "product_type_id":"adsfkasjd12312",
   "working_time":320,
   "datetime": ISODate("2017-09-11T10:10:00Z"),
   "price":60000,
   "office_id":"testoffice",
   "wage":40000,
   "manager_id":"653d047a-e9e3-4161-b2b6-7308f9ad38e5",
   "product_id":"543bee5b-43a0-4c98-976f-a371cafb33e4",
   "aptype":"periodic",
   "cancel_date":[  
      ISODate("2017-09-13T00:00:00Z")
   ]
}
```

---

```
{  
   "_id":"5df00497-e95a-4124-abb0-2ade426c741f",
   "product_type_id":"adsfkasjd12312",
   "working_time":320,
   "datetime": ISODate("2017-09-03T10:10:00Z"),
   "wage":100000,
   "aptype":"periodic",
   "dows":[  
      "1",
      "4",
      "6"
   ],
   "price":111111,
   "active":1,
   "weekend_price":70000,
   "weekend_wage":50000,
   "user_id":"c1676bd5-d9b3-452d-8c93-f710176bb33c",
   "office_id":"testoffice",
   "product_id":"140ceaad-1832-444c-95f6-c8053b242bcb",
   "manager_id":""
}
```

---

```
{  
   "_id":"e5d5a046-caf7-4372-a101-f5260ec0af0a",
   "product_type_id":"adsfkasjd12312",
   "working_time":320,
   "datetime": ISODate("2017-09-02T10:10:00Z"),
   "wage":40000,
   "aptype":"one_time",
   "price":60000,
   "active":1,
   "weekend_price":60000,
   "weekend_wage":40000,
   "user_id":"c1676bd5-d9b3-452d-8c93-f710176bb33c",
   "office_id":"testoffice",
   "product_id":"543bee5b-43a0-4c98-976f-a371cafb33e4",
   "manager_id":""
}
```

So my desired result will be(cancel_date field removed `where _id='8de3e5ec-caa9-4497-89a9-239713e2a2ed'`)

```
{  
   "_id":"8de3e5ec-caa9-4497-89a9-239713e2a2ed",
   "user_id":"6b54be23-0880-4e22-8882-93feea935f12",
   "weekend_price":60000,
   "weekend_wage":40000,
   "active":1,
   "dows":[  
      "2",
      "1",
      "6"
   ],
   "product_type_id":"adsfkasjd12312",
   "working_time":320,
   "datetime": ISODate("2017-09-11T10:10:00Z"),
   "price":60000,
   "office_id":"testoffice",
   "wage":40000,
   "manager_id":"653d047a-e9e3-4161-b2b6-7308f9ad38e5",
   "product_id":"543bee5b-43a0-4c98-976f-a371cafb33e4",
   "aptype":"periodic"
}
```

---

```
{  
   "_id":"5df00497-e95a-4124-abb0-2ade426c741f",
   "product_type_id":"adsfkasjd12312",
   "working_time":320,
   "datetime": ISODate("2017-09-03T10:10:00Z"),
   "wage":100000,
   "aptype":"periodic",
   "dows":[  
      "1",
      "4",
      "6"
   ],
   "price":111111,
   "active":1,
   "weekend_price":70000,
   "weekend_wage":50000,
   "user_id":"c1676bd5-d9b3-452d-8c93-f710176bb33c",
   "office_id":"testoffice",
   "product_id":"140ceaad-1832-444c-95f6-c8053b242bcb",
   "manager_id":""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this document how to eliminate field in select in mongodb . 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

for example

```
db.yourtablename.find( { aptype : 'periodic' }, {  cancel_date :0 } )
```

this query will remove cancel_date in select statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However this will only bring the document where cancel_date exists and I also want to bring the document where cancel_date does not exists.

Comment: This will bring both the document . Check onces. This query means elimiate cancel_date if in the data in mongodb

Comment: Oh yes you are right I thought totally wrong way  thanks.